# Swagger UI Freeze/Crash - Asp.Net Core 3.1. Any fix?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, nswag

I use swashbuckle in my ASP.Net Core 3.1 with swagger UI.
When I click on a model, the whole webpage crashes/freezes.
I use a lot (100 approx) Entity Framework Core entities (7000 lines of JSON).

I switched to Nswag to see if it would be better. No more crashes but still quite slow (10 seconds when you click on a model, 20 on a method)

Should I make DTOs or is there a solution for my problem?

I also tried adding this to my startup but it does not help at all.

```
     services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
        {
            x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Comment: Just make sure you are using latest of the swagger UI... if you are, best you can do is open an issue on the swagger-ui project with your swagger.json:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md

Comment: There are similar issues reported: - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4280
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to NSwag and using DTOs. The lag/crash is gone.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are reporting it seems that your swashbuckle is using an old version of the swagger-ui, there should not be any significant difference from Nswag and swashbuckle if they have the same version of swagger-ui.

But this issue has been discussed on the project, complex nested models when fully expanded are huge, here is some data I collected a while back:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4411#issuecomment-380168870

```
| Schema                                                     | SchemaSize | ExampleSize | ModelSize  |
|------------------------------------------------------------|------------|-------------|------------|
| http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/NestedSwag/2 | 1,368      | 10,578      | 262,519    |
| http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/NestedSwag/3 | 1,662      | 59,703      | 1,321,999  |
| http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/NestedSwag/4 | 1,956      | 332,828     | 6,640,079  |
| http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/NestedSwag/5 | 2,250      | 1,835,953   | 33,305,772 |
```

As you can see expanding those complex models can be a costly task on the browser.

Comment: I had a nested object in a request object referencing itself, this caused it to hang on my side.